# UNIX: Ignore files or directory with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I try to write a script, which it takes regex to ignore files.

for example, I would like to ignore all directory or files which contain 2016, so I will write in regex "2016$" into variable IGN. but I get an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'"

```
max=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
original=$(find . -type f)

for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    check=$(find . -type f | head -n "${i}" | tail -n -1 | tr '\/' '\n' | egrep -n "${IGN}")

    if [ ! -z "$check" ]; then
        original=$(echo ${original} | sed '${i}d')
    fi

done

echo $original
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry men , but Why you write script for do that ?
for example :

```
mkdir test ; cd test
touch File1_2016 File2_2016 File3_2016 File4_2011 File5_2011
mkdir Dir1_2016 Dir2_2016 Dir3_2016 Dir4_2000 Dir5_2000
```

now files is :

```
> ls -l  
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 mahsom mahsom 4096 Mar 28 21:12 Dir1_2016
drwxrwxr-x 2 mahsom mahsom 4096 Mar 28 21:12 Dir2_2016
drwxrwxr-x 2 mahsom mahsom 4096 Mar 28 21:12 Dir3_2016
drwxrwxr-x 2 mahsom mahsom 4096 Mar 28 21:12 Dir4_2000
drwxrwxr-x 2 mahsom mahsom 4096 Mar 28 21:12 Dir5_2000
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahsom mahsom    0 Mar 28 21:12 File1_2016
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahsom mahsom    0 Mar 28 21:12 File2_2016
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahsom mahsom    0 Mar 28 21:12 File3_2016
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahsom mahsom    0 Mar 28 21:12 File4_2011
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahsom mahsom    0 Mar 28 21:12 File5_2011
```

Okey , Now you want to ignore all files has 2016 on last of the name , True ?
Use this command :

```
find . -regextype sed ! -regex ".*2016$"
.
./Dir4_2000
./Dir5_2000
./File4_2011
./File5_2011
```

so , you need variable ?
Do this :

```
ARR=$(find . -regextype sed ! -regex ".*2016$" | sed '1d')
```

This test for you :)

```
for I in ${ARR[@]} ; do echo $I; done
```

Note : Sorry , My English language is not too good . I hope this answer help you .

Answer (score 1):

For `"2016$"` better use globbing `"*2016"`, so you can simply

```
find . -type f -not -name \*2016
```

If you absolutely want regular expressions, write your file list into a temporary file:

```
fn=/tmp/file-$$.list
ffn=/tmp/filtered-file-$$.list
umask 077   # don't leak to other users
find . -type f > $fn
grep -v $EXPRESSION $fn > $ffn
cat $ffn
rm $fn $ffn
```